# Font Weight Unresponsive

Tags: html, css

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8"> 
<!-- Latest compiled and minified CSS -->
<link rel="stylesheet"       href="http://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css">

<!-- jQuery library -->
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.0/jquery.min.js"></script>

<!-- Latest compiled JavaScript -->
<script src="http://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script> 
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
<link href='https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Lato:400,300,100' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css'>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/styles.css">
</head>
<body>
<div class="container">
    <div class="row">
     <div class="col-md-6"><img src="http://placehold.it/150x150" class="img-responsive title-logo"></div>
     <div class="col-md-6 text-right text-uppercase title-thin">
     <h1>Trevor Cleworth</h1>
     <h3>Junior Web Developer</h3>
     </div>
    </div>
    <div class="row">
        <hr>
    </div>
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-12">
            <img src="http://placehold.it/1400x350" class="img-responsive">
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-12">
         <h3>Featured Work</h3>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="row text-center">
        <div class="col-md-3">
         <img src="http://placehold.it/220x220" class="img-responsive">
         <h3>Appify</h3>
         <p><a href="https://github.com/">Click to see</a></p>
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-3">
         <img src="http://placehold.it/220x220" class="img-responsive">
         <h3>Appify</h3>
         <p><a href="https://github.com/">Click to see</a></p>
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-3">
         <img src="http://placehold.it/220x220" class="img-responsive">
          <h3>Appify</h3>
          <p><a href="https://github.com/">Click to see</a></p>
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-3">
         <img src="http://placehold.it/220x220" class="img-responsive">
          <h3>Appify</h3>
          <p><a href="https://github.com/">Click to see</a></p>
        </div>  
    </div> 
</div>
```

This is the code that is connected with my CSS file, the font family will work but the font weight will not, does anyone see why this is? I will link my CSS below. I have been trying to figure out the problem for about thirty minutes but I haven't been able to find anything. If somebody could please show me what the problem is I would appreciate it a ton!

```
body {
  font-family: 'Lato', sans-serif;
  font-weight: 300;
  color: #333333;
}
```

Comment: Try to create an [MCVE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) to demonstrate the problem.

Comment: Place `<meta>` first, then `<link>`, then `<script>` Test your font by setting up identical `<p>` at different `font-weights`. BTW, you have a very limited range of 100, 300, and 400. The difference between them is not that great.

Comment: I'm also assuming that you closed your page with the `</body>` and `</html>` closing tags as well...

Comment: What browser are you using ?  Font weight 300 and 400 is very close. Try importing weight 700 as well and see if you can see the difference. For webkit browsers sometimes you need to do -webkit-font-smoothing: antialiased to see a clear difference between 300 and 400.

Answer (score 0):

add `@import url(http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Lato);`  to your css sheet.
then tell me how it works, I don't have Lato font in my Windows fonts on my laptop